# How to send this SOAP request with PHP

Tags: php, soap

I'm trying to integrate with a third party API and their API accpets only SOAP requests. They have this sample in their documentation. All I need is to replace the agentcode and mpin. Pls I need some one to help me write a PHP code to send the below format to this link http://202.140.50.116/EstelServices/services/EstelServices?wsdl using SOAP request

```
<soapenv:Envelope 
xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" 
xmlns:ser="http://services.estel.com" 
xmlns:bal="http://balance.support.services.estel.com">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <ser:getBalance>
         <ser:balanceRequest>
            <bal:agentCode>TPR_CM</bal:agentCode>
            <bal:mpin>EE17F932B3C311E8877F999DD7865E11</bal:mpin>
         </ser:balanceRequest>
      </ser:getBalance>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Heres what I have tried so far

```
        $xml = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>'.
            '<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ser="http://services.estel.com" xmlns:bal="http://balance.support.services.estel.com">'.
            '<soapenv:Header/>'.
            '<soapenv:Body>'.
            '<ser:getBalance>'.
                '<ser:balanceRequest>'.
                    '<bal:agentCode>TPR_CM</bal:agentCode>'.
                    '<bal:mpin>EE17F932B3C311E8877F999DD7865E11</bal:mpin>'.
                '</ser:balanceRequest>'.
            '</ser:getBalance>'.
            '</soapenv:Body>'.
        '</soapenv:Envelope>';

    $url = "http://balance.support.services.estel.com";

    $soap_do = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($soap_do, CURLOPT_URL,            $url );
    curl_setopt($soap_do, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true );
    curl_setopt($soap_do, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($soap_do, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
    curl_setopt($soap_do, CURLOPT_POST,           true );
    curl_setopt($soap_do, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,    $xml);

    $result = curl_exec($soap_do);
    $err = curl_error($soap_do);
    var_dump($result);
```

Comment: Can you also explain how it is not working?

Comment: I keep getting boolean: false.

Comment: to call soap api , use SoapClient not curl

Comment: @Yinka Updated answer with responce output. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this simple script, which gives you enough information. Function and type lists will help you to make correct SOAP call:

```
<?php
// SOAP
$soap = new SoapClient("http://202.140.50.116/EstelServices/services/EstelServices?wsdl");

// List functions
echo 'Functions: '.'</br>';
$functions = $soap->__getFunctions();
foreach($functions as $item) {
    echo $item.'</br>';
}
echo '</br>';

// List types
echo 'Types: '.'</br>';
$types = $soap->__getTypes();
foreach($types as $item) {
    echo $item.'</br>';
}
echo '</br>';

// Consume SOAP
$params = array(
    "balanceRequest" => array(
        "agentCode" => "TPR_CM",
        "mpin" => "EE17F932B3C311E8877F999DD7865E11"
    )              
);   

// Consume SOAP
$responce = $soap->getBalance($params);
foreach($responce->getBalanceReturn as $name => $value) {
   echo $name.': '.$value.'<br>';
}   
?>
```

Comment: You are a legend @Zhorov. Thanks alot. Pls I need one more help from u. I cant seem to figure it out myself. Its the top up part. Pls can I have your email?

Answer (score 0):

Use the PHP native SoapClient along with the service WSDL:

```
$atservices_wsdl = "http://202.140.50.116/EstelServices/services/EstelServices?wsdl";
$atservices_client = new SoapClient($atservices_wsdl);

$balance = $atservices_client->getBalance("TPR_CM","EE17F932B3C311E8877F999DD7865E11");

print_r($balance); // review the returned object converted from SOAP response.
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But only Zhorov answer worked